# Apache Cassandra num_tokens ideal value for write heavy application

Tags: cassandra

I am setting up Cassandra 3.11 cluster and wanted to know what is the ideal value for num_tokens. By default, cassandra.yaml has 256. Some blogs on Cassandra suggests values  for num_tokens to be 32. Do we see any performance issue with 256 num_tokens or can we have values like 16 or 32.  How can we decide the optimal value?  Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num_tokens` value as such as no impact on writing. Most of the issue with having large value of `num_tokens` is with operation maintenance (repair) and scanning issues while reading. High `num_token` value is found to create hotspots, also more parition ranges increase repair time. Community has reduced default value of `num_tokens` from 256 to 16 in Cassandra 4.0 release. You can see JIRA [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13701).

You can experiment with lower values of num_tokens. Don't forget to use `allocate_tokens_for_keyspace`([Cassandra Documentation](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/3.11/cassandra/configuration/cass_yaml_file.html)

Comment: Hi Manish,  you mentioned - scanning issues while reading, means read queries will have any performance issue?

Comment: if hotspots are there certain nodes may have more data than other nodes, means they need to do more work and performance may get hampered due to that. Basic idea is that you want equal distribution among nodes and avoid hotspots. Community is surely moving towards lower values of num_tokens. Personally I have no experience with low num_token values.